# Is it possible to download the 'inspect element' data from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been trying to access the inspect element data from a certain website (The regular source code won't work for this). At first I tried rendering the javascript for the site. I've tried using selenium, pyppeteer, webbot, phantomjs, and request_html + beautifulsoup. All of these did not work. Would it be possible to simply copy-paste this data using python?

The data I need is from https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6 and looks like this:

```
<nav class="feature-list">
    <span style="" id="ember683" class="flex-horizontal feature-list-item ember-view">
```

(all span's in this certain nav)

Comment: What are you seeing in the inspect window that you are not able to get with selenium.  Could you add the html.

Comment: Maybe share the URL?

Comment: It would be better if you add some screenshots on what do you want to extract on the website

Comment: You can do 'Copy outerHTML' from the panel and paste it into a text file

Comment: @pguardiario I was trying to do this programmatically so that I woudn't need to copy-paste the data every few minutes.

Comment: @Clinton that's what selenium is for

Comment: @ClintonGraham Could you share the URL? It's possible the page you are trying to scrape makes a request to an API, the result of which it uses to populate the DOM.

Comment: There is no need for you to crawl that website. The data is publicly avaliable on their [GitHub](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data)

Comment: You will have to us selenium to click to the through the site to get to the same point where you inspected the element.

Comment: @drec4s Finally, 3 days, 230 lines of code, and 50+ chrome tabs later, I finally found a solution. Thanks a million.